# Why isn't a boolean column being persisted to my database with EF Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-migration

So I've got this POCO that represents a table in my database:

```
// BaseDataObject includes the Id property among others.
public class SupplierDocument : BaseDataObject
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Document { get; set; }
    public bool Alerted { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbSet<PaymentTerm> PaymentTerms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SupplierDocument> SupplierDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SupplierService> SupplierServices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Voucher> Vouchers { get; set; }


    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DevConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

I added the `Alerted` property in a later migration which I've done an update to the database with:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Suppliers", "Area", c => c.String());
    AddColumn("dbo.Vouchers", "IssuedFor", c => c.String());
    AddColumn("dbo.SupplierDocuments", "Alerted", c => c.Boolean());
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.Vouchers", "IssuedFor");
    DropColumn("dbo.Suppliers", "Area");
    DropColumn("dbo.SupplierDocuments", "Alerted");
}
```

Paradoxically, the column doesn't get added to the table when I `update-database` after adding the migration.

The thing is, I had to manually add the column as it wasn't included in the migration by default after `add-migration`.

Short of deleting all the migrations and starting over with the current model (which experience has shown me isn't guaranteed to fix the problem anyway), how can I make this work and why doesn't it work anyway?

Comment: I can't even say conclusively that this happens *only* with boolean fields. That's just the case this time.

Comment: I have another connection string in web.config called *"LiveConnection"* which targets a remote database instead of .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: What does `update-database -verbose` show?

Comment: Do you have data in that table? May be you can try specifying nullable and default value attributes in your AddColumn call. Just like -
 AddColumn("dbo.SupplierDocuments", "Alerted", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));

Comment: New problem: every time I try `update-database` it errors saying *"There is already an object named 'PaymentTerms' in the database."*

Comment: @Nirman yes there was a record in that table... I had to delete the whole database to get this to work which is actually something I wanted to avoid

Comment: @Ortund - yes sure. there definitely is a way to perform this without a need to delete the database. May be next time you can try out the option I have suggested.

Comment: @Nirman please add an answer for the record :) Now I think of it, you're probably right. It wouldn't add the column for risk of corrupting the data already present in the table.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have records in that particular table, you may be getting an error in the background suggesting potential loss of data.

Try supplying "nullable" and "defaultValue" properties in the AddColumn statement

```
AddColumn("dbo.SupplierDocuments", "Alerted", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
```